# Facebook login message: “URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings.”

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I am using laravel socialite. But in redirect message, I found Facebook login message: “URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the client and web OAuth logins are on and add all your app domains as valid OAuth redirect URIs.”
I have set App Domains and redirect_uri.
Settings Pics Are Attached

[Response i get from redirect url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVPF7.png)

[The actual message on redirect from facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1pDu.png)

[redirect uri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViWvF.png)

[my App Domains settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWC6I.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect uri should be the uri you want to go to after authentication. Let's say you want to go to https://www.example.net/dashboard , you should have it listed in your valid OAuth redirect URIs in your app setting. So while performing your OAuth operation, your url should have :

...oauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.example.net%2Fdashboard...

Comment: Yes, thank you problem is solved. It was redirected URIs problem.